# Changing WebForms site to .NET 4.7 generates compilation error message

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I am getting the following message when compiling a previously working ASP.NET WebForms site:

*The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: The type initializer for 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.AssemblyUtils' threw an exception*

I am converting the site from .NET 4.6.1 to .NET 4.7.1. Aside from the appropriate changes in the Web.config, there have been no changes to the code. In particular, I have searched the Web.config for the `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true">` line mentioned in other solutions and have not found it.

The only other change the solution has gone through is the addition of the MSTest's TestAdapter from NuGet. Could that be relevant?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** One non-change that might be relevant: One of the references in the project is System.Web.Helpers, version 3.0.0.0. I wonder if it is incompatible with .NET 4.7.1...

Comment: You should look at the `InnerException` of the `TypeInitializationException` to see what the "real" problem is using a debugger.

Comment: Perhaps this is a dumb question, but how do get at the debugger during a compilation in VS2017?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem - it had nothing to do with System.Web.Helpers, nor TestAdapter. I explicitly set the following:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
```

This also required adding a reference to System.Web.Infrastructure to the project, but once this was done, it compiled and ran without any problems.

Comment: You are a hero! was converting older project to 4.8 and this worked although I used Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure . (for anyone else here I also updated  targetFramework location in webconfig to 4.8)